# how can i disable the button based on mapped inputs validation in react js

Tags: reactjs, mapping

i have mapped the inputs and written validation for them based on minimum and maximum value, if i get the error validation in any one of the input in mapping, disable the button that is outside of the mapping, how can i achieve this?

i tried using useState hook, when i get the error in more than one input field it disables the button,but if i solve the error of one field and leaving other fields error as it is, still i got the enabled button, actually i want to enable button, once all the error validation is solved, please help me out from this, thanking you

Comment: share your code, so that we can take a look at the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.